# Register users with magic link in firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-dynamic-links

I'm working on a product being targeted to companies with employees. We get a collection of employee emails to which we need to register them for an account on our firebase platform.

Ideally what I'd like to do is use this data to create all the user accounts on firebase then email them all a unique magic key to verify their registration and let them input a password.

Unfortunately I'm a bit stuck on making the magic link custom tailored to the users email. Looking at firebases dynamic link creator it doesn't look like there's a way to create a dynamic magic link where I can input something unique about the user account to later identify them after they click on it to give them the correct onboarding platform.

Any ideas how I could accomplish this?

Comment: This is a really open ended question and kinda falls outside the guidelines of SO (so it may be closed). This is a difficult issue. If you set up users in a Firebase node /users which contains say, their email and a 'magic key', that node would need to be read by an unregistered user. That's obviously a problem as then anyone could read that node. I would suggest either having your app register them (where they can input their email and a pw) or perhaps creating the users in Firebase, and then sending them a password reset email via Firebase? Haven't tried that but it may be an option.

Answer (score 1):

You can create tailored Firebase Dynamic Links for each of your users. If you creating links server side, check out REST API https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/rest .

For example in this long dynamic link `https://abc123.app.goo.gl/?link=https://example.com/&apn=com.example.android&ibi=com.example.ios` the deep link is `https://example.com/`. You can use deep link looking like `https://example.com/invite_user?user_id=<here unique user id>`.

You may need to check out Firebase Authentication https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ as well. Better to create separate question for each step you seeking advise.